# Remove line breaks \n from text in R

Tags: r, line-breaks

I would like to remove all line breaks from my text, in order to transform it afterwards to a tidy table separated by single words:

```
##load text##
files <- list.files(path = file.path(here(), "data"), pattern = "pdf$")
Indy_movies <- lapply(paste0(file.path(here()),"/data/",files), pdf_text)
```

**Result:**

[image: Text]

I can already see that the text is separated by \n.

```
##transform to tibble##
Indy_movies <- tibble(movie = c("Indy1", "Indy2", "Indy3", "Indy4"), text = as.character(Indy_movies))
```

Transforming the data with the `unnest_tokens()` function:

```
Indy_movies %>%
  unnest_tokens(word, text)
```

**Result:**

[image: Text]

The word "the" still contains the line break "n"...which results in the word "nthe".

What I tried already:

```
Indy_movies = str_replace_all(Indy_movies, pattern = c("\n" = ""))
```

This returned the error: `argument is not an atomic vector; coercing`. Thanks!

Comment: If you had a snippet of reproducible data, ppl would surely and more easily help you.

Answer (score 2):

In the absence of reproducible data here's something to get you started:

Data:

```
Indy_movies <- "The hovitos are near.\nThe poison etc.\nSome more text"
```

To remove `\n`, use `gsub` and appropriate escaping:

```
gsub("\\n", " ", Indy_movies)
[1] "The hovitos are near. The poison etc. Some more text"
```